# I can't understand the logic with power = voltage * current

Tags: voltage, current

I mean, if I have a 2000W device and plug it in a 220V outlet, it will produce about 9,1A.

But if somehow the outlet is not delivering 220v, but less, like 180V, according to the equation, it will produce 11,1A.

But how decreasing voltage increases current if voltage is the 'provider' of current?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the existing questions on this site about voltage and current?

Comment: If the load is a simpe resistor/heater then no, the current will drop and the total power is P=U^2/R.

Comment: A 2000W device in a 220V outlet will not _produce_ 9.1 ampere...

Comment: Think about what a 2000 watt device might mean - it might mean that if you turned the supply off it would try and extract 2000W from the surroundings by whatever means i.e. get in the way and you are ice. Or it could mean that it's a bit of medium resistance wire that only consumes 2000W when connected to the correct voltage.

Comment: What is the device? If the device is a resistor or other passive network then reducing the voltage will reduce the current. But, if your device is active say a bench power supply or a TV for example then it needs a certain power to run and will take more current at lower voltages to do this.  We need more information to answer this question fully.

Comment: The power utility will 'produce' (supply actually) the current that your device 'uses' (draws traditionally).  You will get more and better assistance if you correct your queastion.

Answer (score 6):

If the device in question actually draws 2000W fixed, then you are correct.

For example, if I have a 48V switching supply connected to a 1.152\$\Omega\$ resistor, the input current will increase as the input voltage decreases to maintain the same output power.

However **most devices do not behave that way**. The current will decrease as the voltage decreases, and the power will decrease even faster than the current (with the square of the voltage for a resistor, somewhat less for most heaters because the resistance drops with decreasing temperature).

If I have a 220V heater rated at 2000W it will be about 24.2 ohms. If it stays 24.2 ohms, on 180V it will draw 180/24.2 = 7.44A and dissipate about 1339W (P = I * V). You can also calculate it from \$P = (\frac{180VAC}{220VAC})^2 \cdot 2000W\$ = 1339W.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the switching power supply counterintuitive input side current characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Decreasing the voltage doesn't increase the current. It decreases the current and power (in a resistive model for simplicity).

I=V/R. The resistance is nominally constant, so the lower the voltage the lower the current. Thus the product of voltage times current is also lower, in fact it decreases by a square law.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the case. If you lower the voltage, the current also goes down. That is, your device doesn't always put out 2000W or whatever the maximum output power is.

***I am assuming here that your device supplies power, e.g. power supply, not a load in this example...***

Your device can **deliver up to** 2000W at 220V, that is its maximum capability. That is the max power it can provide. But even if you were supplying the device 220V, it doesn't mean it has to output 9.1A (or 2000 Watts in terms of power). The load will determine how much current it needs to operate.

You can have a load that will draw 5 Amps, that just depends on the load. If that's the case, then your device will be providing \$ P= (5A)(220V)= 1100W\$.

You would reach the device's max rating if you keep adding loads or a single load that takes up the rest of the power. Let's say you add a load, on top of the previous one, that draws 6 Amps. Now, that last load is using up 1320 Watts. Since you already had a load at 1100 Watts, this last load will max out your device (1100W+1320W= 2420 Watts). Your device will provide as much as it can which is 2000 Watts. Although pushing it past its max rating will probably burn it out.

Hope it helps.